# Input/output error when reading disk

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, io, bad-blocks

I did a forced shutdown after my computer froze (on Ubuntu). After turning back on I found a "attempt to read or write outside of disk `hd0`" error, after choosing Ubuntu on GRUB.

I haven then booted on Boot Repair Disk Linux and tried to use dd to read the MBR, and have gotten an input/output error:

> lubuntu@lubuntu:~$ sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/home/MBR.image bs=446 count=1
>
> dd: error reading ‘/dev/sda’: Input/output error
>
> 0+0 records in
>
> 0+0 records out
>
> 0 bytes (0 B) copied, 0.000463131 s, 0.0 kB/s

I have also run `sudo badblocks -s` and get all the blocks being bad. ALL of them, as far as I can bother to let it run, at least. It sounds like the output of badblocks can't be right to me..

Also if GRUB is stored in the MBR of my disk, and there is an input/output error when I try to access it, how can the BIOS access it?

Thanks!

Comment: The block size should be 512, not 446.  Grub is not stored in the MBR.

Comment: Are you by any chance running an SSD ?  It could be your drive is poked.  Also, are you sure that when ou use the Boot Repair Disk your hard drive is innumerated as /dev/sda ?

Comment: @sawdust Grub can be installed onto the MBR - See http://superuser.com/questions/131638/grub-in-mbr-or-partition for example