# How do I choose which GRUB the MBR looks at with multiple linux distributions?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub, mbr

I have two instances of Ubuntu running on my computer (The second one is for an operating systems class).

The problem is that when I installed the second Ubuntu, the MBR now looks at the second GRUB, even though the second partition is not flagged as bootable (using cfdisk).

How do I make the MBR to look at the first partition's GRUB?

edit: The only reason I care is in the case I brick the second Ubuntu Dist, I do not want the chance of bricking my computer.

Comment: I think it has to do with your stage 1 grub, which I think goes on your MBR. I believe grub-setup /dev/sdX (no partition number) is how a running system would get its stage 1 inplanted..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have grub loaded into the VBR of both partitions (see this fantastic Superuser post on [How boot sectors work](https://superuser.com/questions/107235/how-do-boot-sectors-and-multiple-drives-works/108152#108152)), you can simply boot your original install and re-install grub.

From the section "Reinstalling Grub" on https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing

> After installing another operating system which installed its own
>   bootloader, reinstall GRUB2 to return control to the desired OS. When
>   an operating system is added on a multiboot computer it will generally
>   take command of the boot process. Reinstalling GRUB 2 from a within
>   the desired OS will return control of the boot process to that OS.

Grub [ignores the boot flag](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26688/grub-and-boot-loader) nowadays anyway.

If you are in the habit of installing multiple OSes, you may want to consider creating a [dedicated grub partition.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54416/creating-a-dedicated-grub-partition-before-installing-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

Boot the Ubuntu which you want to be first in the bootloader and run:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sdX
sudo update-grub
```

Where X is the letter of the hard disk on which your GRUB is installed (probably "a")